# :after pseudo class not working outside Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Using JQuery I have an error check that adds a class to an `<input>` checkbox. That has an `:after` pseudo class, but the information displayed by that class doesn't appear.

Tried a couple of things to get it to work, but no dice. This is the site I am working on: [SITE](https://www.metsales.com/ncr/ipc%20landing%20page/ipc.html#lp5)

The only other reason that I can think of for this not to work is that the page would need to be refreshed with the addition of a new class...but everything else that I add a new class to it works.

The error check appears when the checkbox is checked and there is no scanner selected.

Here is all of my relevant code:

### HTML

```
<form id="lp5_form" class="prodForm">
    <label><span>Apple Product: </span><select class="model">
                            <option value="0">iPod 5</option>
                            <option value="1">iPhone 5</option>
                         </select></label>
    <label style="padding: 10px 0;"><h4>Sled Options :</h4></label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Encryption Capability: </td><td><select class="encryption">
                                                   <option value="0">Standard</option>
                                                   <option value="1">SRED for PCI Compliancy</option>
                                                 </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                                         
            <td>Scanner: </td><td><select class="scanner">
                                    <option value="0">None</option>
                                    <option value="1">1D</option>
                                    <option value="2">2D</option>
                                  </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bluetooth: </td><td><input class="bt" type="checkbox" value="bluetooth" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

### CSS

```
.pn_error{}

.pn_error:after, .pn_error::after {
    content: "*Please select a scanner";
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    left: 20px;
    top: -2px;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

### JQUERY Error Check

```
if(scanner == 0) {
    bt = 0;
    $(id+' .bt').addClass('pn_error');
}
```

As usual all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:after` is a psuedo-element, not a psuedo-class. As such, they cannot be applied to element that do not allow children. So no `img:after`, no `br:after`, and no `input:after`.

Comment: Nice catch. Was searching the reason aswell!

Comment: To verify what **Niet the Dark Absol** is saying, if you look at your own source code using Chrome's inspector, you'll see how Chrome is treating `::after`: `<input class="bt pn_error" type="checkbox" value="bluetooth">::after</input>`. This is syntactically incorrect, but Chrome will render it anyway.

Comment: This is much appreciated... do you have a list of elements that do not allow children?

Comment: @Adjit `area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-elements   That's said, not all element with children can have pseudo element applied, as SELECT

Comment: @Adjit Any element that doesn't store its content as a DOM child node.

Comment: @Adjit probably all self closing element. You can detect self-closing element by their syntaxe e.g. : `<input />`.